# Parsing jQuery's .get() AJAX method

Tags: php, jquery

I've been struggling with parsing an HTML AJAX response all day. Currently my jQuery looks like this:

```
$.get("check-in.php", {value: inputValue}).done(function(data) {
  //Show results in HTML document
  var checkinSuccessStr = $("<p/>", { html: data }).find("#success").html();
  var checkinFailStr = $("<p/>", { html: data }).find("#fail").html();
  console.log(checkinSuccessStr); //Works
  console.log(checkinFailStr); //Works

  var dataDump = data;
  console.log($(dataDump).filter("#result-table").html()); //Syntax error
});
```

My PHP file `check-in.php` looks like this:

```
<p id="success">2 entries were good</p>
<p id="fail">1 entry couldn't be found</p>
<table id="result-table>...<!--arbitrary list of successful entries--></table>
```

The simple `<p>` tags can be parsed easily, but no luck with the `<table>`. I've tried using PHP's `json_encode()` and giving it the HTML strings, but no luck there. The second-last line is a reproduction of a response I found on here from 6 years ago, in addition to other similar solutions proposed. Thus I wouldn't consider this question a duplicate for that reason. I'm really not sure what to do at this point. I'm currently using version 3.1.1 of jQuery, for what it's worth.

If anyone has a solution to parsing the complete HTML table string, or instead a more simpler solution to transferring the data table that I haven't realized, please let me know! Thanks

Comment: Why are you putting the response HTML into a `<p>` tag? Twice? Also, the `id` attribute value for your `<table>` is missing a closing quote character

Comment: What **exactly** is this _"syntax error"_ you speak of?

Comment: jsut pass the table values array as the response and use $.each and  generate the table  would be less load  on your server to generate the whole table ...also the response load would be smaller   also success and pass